# Performance drop after upgrading to .NET 4.5

Tags: .net, performance, .net-4.5

After upgrading .NET 4 to .NET 4.5, my application starts using more and more memory and gets slower and slower over time.

This application is a Windows service, compiled against .NET 4, but in Visual Studio 2013.

The application makes extensive use of the Task Parallel Library, but everywhere I read about performance improvements for the TPL.

Are there any performance gotcha's/changes between 4 and 4.5?

Comment: What does your application do?

Comment: [The .NET Framework 4.5 includes new garbage collector enhancements for client and server apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually fixed by "optimizing" the Garbage Collector. Normally, you shouldn't have to do this. But we added this to our app.config (under the `runtime` section):

```
<gcServer enabled="true" />
<gcConcurrent enabled="true" />
```